# reactiveFileReader in Shiny will not update when new files are added to the reactive filePath

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I am using the reactiveFileReader function in an R Shiny app to read in and visualize data that are being logged in real time (1 second data). The data files are being stored in a single folder but a new file is created every hour. I am using a reactive file path that should update when a new file is created and begin reading in and plotting data from the new file, however, reactiveFileReader does not seem to be reactive to changes in the filePath argument. The app just freezes at the last data point from the previous file until I refresh the whole app, at which time the new file is visualized.

Here is a snippet of the code I am using to read in the data.

```
dir <- "/media/sf_D_DRIVE"      
file_name <- reactive({paste0(dir, "/", list.files(dir)[length(list.files(dir))])})
df_1 <- reactiveFileReader(intervalMillis = 100, session = session , filePath =  file_name, readFunc = read.csv)
```

I've also tried putting the filePath directly as an argument.

```
dir <- "/media/sf_D_DRIVE"      
df_1 <- reactiveFileReader(intervalMillis = 100, session = session , filePath =  paste0(dir, "/", list.files(dir)[length(list.files(dir))]), readFunc = read.csv)
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to have the filePath update reactively and the app read and visualize data from the new files added to the folder without having to refresh?

Unfortunately, it is challenging to provide a reproducible example since you would need the data logging and file creation side of the example to make it work. Hopefully someone still has some ideas! Thanks!

Comment: when using a reactive you should use parenthesis :  `filePath =  file_name()` but here you don't need reactive just use base directory `df_1 <- reactiveFileReader(intervalMillis = 100, session = session , filePath =  dir, readFunc = read.csv)` and don't forget the parenthesis when calling it : `df_1()`

Comment: @HubertL dir is just a directory, not a file so its not being pointed at a specific file to open in the case you suggested. How does reactiveFileReader know which file to read? And, yes, I know to use parenthesis with reactive dataframes, however, in the case of reactiveFileReader, I found when using a reactive filePath argument parenthesis after it did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reactiveFileReader` is based on `reactivePoll`. You can use `reactivePoll` to achieve what you want:

```
df_1 <- reactivePoll(
  1000, session,
  checkFunc = function(){
    # this function returns the most recent modification time in the folder
    files <- list.files(dir, full.names = TRUE)
    info <- file.info(files)
    max(info$mtime)
  },
  valueFunc = function(){
    # this function returns the content of the most recent file in the folder
    files <- list.files(dir, full.names = TRUE)
    info <- file.info(files)
    i <- which.max(info$mtime)
    read.csv(files[i])
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked beautifully and saved me additional days of lost time (after already spending a solid day on it). Very much appreciated!